# Problem with using TikZ pictures as subfigures

Tags: errors, subfloats

I tried to create a figure which consists of two subfigures, each of which is a TikZ picture.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,tikz,caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}

\begin{subfigure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

  \path (0,0) coordinate (P0) node[right=0.1cm] {P0};
  \fill (P0) circle (2pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Hello P1} \label{fig:M1}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

  \path (0,0) coordinate (P0) node[right=0.1cm] {P0};
  \fill (P0) circle (2pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Hello P2} \label{fig:M2}
\end{subfigure}


\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But compiling this file gives the error

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.10 \begin
           {tikzpicture}[scale=1]
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `subfigure` environment has a mandatory argument specifying the width:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,tikz,caption,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

  \path (0,0) coordinate (P0) node[right=0.1cm] {P0};
  \fill (P0) circle (2pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Hello P1} \label{fig:M1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

  \path (0,0) coordinate (P0) node[right=0.1cm] {P0};
  \fill (P0) circle (2pt);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Hello P2} \label{fig:M2}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `.5\linewidth` for each subfigure so each one will occupy half the available horizontal space and the two will appear side-by-side; of course, you can adjust those settings according to your needs. I also used `\centering` to center the objects, since the `center` environment adds (usually unnecessary) vertical spacing inside a float.

Comment: Thank you, Gonzalo. Do you mean `textwidth` or `linewidth`? (In the example you have `linewidth` but in your description you have `textwidth`.) Or are they the same?

Comment: @boaten in my example document they are the same, but they can differ depending in the context (for example, if `twocolumn` is used). I've updated my answer for consistency's sake.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with using TiKz for your figures, it's how you're doing the subfigures.

I write a lot of papers where I want a series of side-by-side (or more complicated) subfloats in my figures. In addition, I'd like the figures to be centered vertically. I finally gave up and switched from subfloat or subfig to using the floatrow package.

Here's a minimal example of using floatrow to place two subfigures side-by-side.

```
\documentclass[]{article}       
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}   
\usepackage{floatrow}   
\floatsetup[figure]{floatrowsep=qquad,   valign=c}      
\floatsetup[subfigure]{subfloatrowsep=qquad, heightadjust=object, valign=c, framefit = yes}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\ffigbox{
\begin{subfloatrow}[2] %change to 3 to have 3 side-by-side subfigs
\ffigbox[.4\textwidth]{\caption{A caption!}}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\ffigbox[.4\textwidth]{\caption{Another nice rectangle}}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (6,2);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{subfloatrow}
}{
\caption{Here is a figure with two subfigures.}
\label{F:FirstEx}
}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```